# Extending behavior of the property decorator

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I would like to extend the behavior of the builtin `@property` decorator. The desired usage is shown in the code below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xy = 42

    @my_property(some_arg="some_value")
    def x(self):
        return self.xy

print(A().x) # should print 42
```

First of all, the decorator should retain the property behavior so that no `()` is needed after the `x`. Next, I would like to be able to access the arguments a programmer passes to my decorator.

I started off with this:

```
class my_property(property):
   def __init__(self, fn):
       super().__init__(fn)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'some_arg'
```

After adding `**kwargs`:

```
class my_property(property):
   def __init__(self, fn, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(fn)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fn'
```

OK, let's do `*args` instead:

```
class my_property(property):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args)

TypeError: 'my_property' object is not callable
```

Let's make it callable:

```
class my_property(property):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

No errors, but prints None instead of 42
```

And now I am lost. I have not even yet managed to access `some_arg="some_value" and the property behavior seems to be already gone. What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: how do you want to access `some_arg` ?

Comment: *so that no () is needed after the x* - how would you expect accessing an instance attribute without instantiating that instance?

Comment: `property` uses some magic to allow this behavior. The problem with what you are trying to achieve here is that any decorator will be defined before the instance is created. Even if you manage to inject `self` in the decorator's run-time (which is possible using function-based decorator) it will be incredibly hard to pass that instance to the "function" (property) you are trying to call. Perhaps it's possible to abuse frame inspections to hack something

Comment: You are getting `None` because you have `pass` in `__call__`. If you change it to `return anything` then `anything` will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you intent to use `some_arg`, but to pass a parameter to a decorator you need to have "two layers" of decorators

```py
@my_decorator(arg)
def foo():
    return
```

under the hood this translates to `my_decorator(arg)(foo)` (i.e. `my_decorator(arg)` must return another decorator that is called with `foo`). The inner decorator in this case should be your custom implementation of property

```py
def my_property(some_arg):
    class inner(object):
        def __init__(self, func):
            print(some_arg)  # do something with some_arg
            self.func = func

        def __get__(self, obj, type_=None):
            return self.func(obj)
    return inner
```

Now you can use it like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @my_property('test!')
    def foo(self):
        return self.x


obj = MyClass(42)  # > test!
obj.foo            # > 42
```

Read more about [descriptors here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)